# PNG-Preview of animated GIF with ImageMagick is distorted

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am creating preview images of all JPG/PNG/GIF that are uploaded to our server.

For this I use ImageMagick with:

```
convert -format jpg -quality 90 -strip -background white -flatten -alpha off +repage -resize '255x255>' ".$locationtmp." -write '".$preview."'");
```

The parameters added are to flatten the background (make it white instead of black).

However, when using the code to create a preview of an animated GIF, the result is distorted.

Example of a distorted result:

[image: PNG distorted]

I tried to add the `+repage` parameter but it did not help.

How to get a nice preview of the GIF as PNG? It could also be just the first frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, if you want a preview image for all formats including gif and want just the first frame of the animation for the preview, then just add [0] to the filename, such as animation.gif[0]. This will take the first frame of the animation and the only frames of the other formats such as JPG and PNG that only allow one frame. The appended [0] does not hurt the other formats.

So use

```
image.suffix[0] in place of just image.suffix
```

for generating a single image preview

Comment: Amazing. It works out of the box! `convert -format jpg -quality 90 -strip -background white -flatten -alpha off +repage -resize '255x255>' ".$locationtmp."[0] -write '".$preview."'");`

Comment: Glad it helped. If you want some other frame, say the 10th frame, then use [9] (as indices start with 0)